# Why can I not embed a processing file into my website?

Tags: web, processing

I created a game in Processing and I need to embed that game into a page on a website for my final year project. It's a space invaders game, that has 3 classes (don't know if that could be the problem).

I followed lots of tutorials online and tried using a JS library, but it doesn't work. All I get is a blank page with a gray square.

Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" 
        width="1000" 
        height="400" 
        style="border:1px solid #000000;"
        dataprocessingsources="maths_game/Programming_Assignment/Programming_Assignment.pde">
</canvas>
```

[The result that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZooFL.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed Processing directly because Processing is Java, and can't be embedded in a website.

You can use Processing.js to port your Processing code to JavaScript, which can be embedded in a website. See [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) on Processing.js.

Note that this means that you can't have used any Java libraries or anything specific to Java in your code. Also note that P5.js is a completely different thing. You can read about different versions of Processing [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/which-processing).

You should also get into the habit of looking at your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools). Any errors you're getting will show up there. My guess is that you're using something Java-specific in your code, or you aren't loading something correctly.

If you still can't get it working, please post a link to an example webpage that embeds a simplified Processing sketch that shows the same error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My only worry is how do I include different classes in the JavaScript. It seems like the tutorial embeds a much simpler code.

Comment: @MónicaCardoso Multiple classes should work fine. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It comes up with the exact same result as shown in the image of my question :(

Comment: @MónicaCardoso Like I said, please look at your developer tools or post a link to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If your Processing sketch consists of multiple classes/pde files, then you should mention all of them in the `data-processing-sources` tag (not "dataprocessingsources").

e.g.

`<canvas id="myCanvas" data-processing-sources="file1.pde file2.pde"></canvas>`